# How to stay in iOS Safari's standalone mode when navigating

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

When in iOS' standalone web app modus, and you click a link, that link is opened in Mobile Safari instead of staying in the standalone modus. This makes no sense to me (at least for internal links).

The only way I can think of fixing this is adding a click handler to the `document` node, and manually navigating like this:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location = e.target.getAttribute('href');
  });
}
```

Is there a less hacky way of obtaining this behavior? This really hurt my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunate something along those lines is the standard way to do it. irae on GitHub has put together a script called [Stay Standalone](https://gist.github.com/irae/1042167) that will handle all the dirty work for you and is tested on a variety of edge cases. Although the script is a bit older, it does work on modern version of iOS.

It might be a bit ugly, but the code is resilient and can be included in a general Javascript bundle. It won't change the behavior for other scenarios. This is just speculation, but the reason I think Apple opted for this behavior is that standalone web apps have no forward or back buttons and clicking a link could put the app in an "unusable" state and for websites not full intended to be apps. This is probably the most desirable behavior in the general case for the end user.

Here is a copy of the Javascript:

```
(function(document,navigator,standalone) {
    // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
    // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
    if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
        var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            curnode=e.target;
            while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                curnode=curnode.parentNode;
            }
            // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
            // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
            if(
                'href' in curnode && // is a link
                (chref=curnode.href).replace(location.href,'').indexOf('#') && // is not an anchor
                (   !(/^[a-z\+\.\-]+:/i).test(chref) ||                       // either does not have a proper scheme (relative links)
                    chref.indexOf(location.protocol+'//'+location.host)===0 ) // or is in the same protocol and domain
            ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                location.href = curnode.href;
            }
        },false);
    }
})(document,window.navigator,'standalone');
```

You can see [the tests here](https://gist.github.com/irae/1042167#file-stay_standalone-html).

Comment: So sad to see that this is the actual approach needed. But thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah I found it to be quite a bummer too. I wish there was a meta tag we could use to opt into a normal link behavior.

Comment: This does not work in latest iOS. Does anyone has a solution already? The location.href is executed but it will open the link in the browser.